# Site not showing I'm logged in

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

After I login with Yahoo OpenID, the page I'm redirected to doesn't show that I'm logged in until I manually refresh it. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Could well be a caching issue and nothing to do with the site... If your ISP or your computer caches the page that you were previously on, then it may just give you the cached copy of that page (from when you weren't logged in) rather than the updated one (where you are logged in).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to log in from my Yahoo account without issues.